# Install slime on emacs error

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, lisp-box

IDE for common lisp like lispbox,lispstick do not work on my windows,so I try to directly install slime on my emacs,but the error still happened.

```
Debugger entered: (("Error in timer" slime-attempt-connection (#<process inferior-lisp> nil 4) (file-error "make client process failed" "too many open files" :name "SLIME Lisp" :buffer nil :host "127.0.0.1" :service 6605 :nowait nil)))
  (condition-case data (apply fun args) ((debug error) (debug nil (list "Error in timer" fun args data))))
  slime-timer-call(slime-attempt-connection #<process inferior-lisp> nil 4)
  apply(slime-timer-call (slime-attempt-connection #<process inferior-lisp> nil 4))
  byte-code("r\301\302H\303H\"\210)\301\207" [timer apply 5 6] 4)
  timer-event-handler([t 21613 26304 366000 nil slime-timer-call (slime-attempt-connection #<process inferior-lisp> nil 4) nil 0])
```

Here is my .emacs file

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/slime-master/") ;your SLIME directory
(setq inferior-lisp-program "D:/eugene_software/sbcl64/sbcl.exe");your Lisp system
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
(require 'slime-autoloads)
```

Comment: The mailing list for that IDE might be a better place to ask about this specifically.

Comment: You don't need any IDE to learn a new programming language. You just need an implementation of that language (an interpreter or a compiler), and a good editor. `emacs` is a good editor.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm an avid Emacs user, so I don't disagree with your claim, but if someone is learning a new programming language and isn't familiar with Emacs, then learning Emacs in addition to the programming language *does* add a lot to learn.

Comment: But then he could use another *editor*. If he is fine with `vim`, or `gedit`, or `notepad`, or `leafpad` or even `ed`, good. Of course I don't recommend `ed` for those not used to it. My point is that IDE are not useful, editors are. So the claim "I need an IDE first" is false.

Comment: Why does this have haskell tag?

Comment: If you decide to try an alternate approach: it is practical to install Emacs and lisp (CCL or SBCL) separately, then install Quicklisp and follow its directions for setting up SLIME to get a nice Common Lisp environment.

Comment: @Chris: Lispbox is just a package of Emacs with SLIME, Quicklisp, and CCL.

Comment: You could try http://www.iqool.de/lispstick.html, if you are on Windows. On Linux the most simple way is to install emacs,slime and sbcl from your distro.

Comment: I downloaded the lispstick and run the bat file,the same error happended.I think maybe it is a slime error.