# emacs slime can not connect to swank

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

After I type `M-x:slime-connect` with emacs on windows7-64,and enter host and port: `host:127.0.0.1` / `port:4005`.

It shows the error:

```
Connecting to Swank on port 4005..
open-network-stream: make client process failed: too many open files, :name, SLIME Lisp, :buffer, nil, :host, 127.0.0.1, :service, 4005, :nowait, nil
```

**How can I fix that and what is the reason behind it?**

Comment: if you installed emacs/slime as a bundle it might be enought to just use `M-x slime`

Comment: Well,this is another problem.Because the connection to swank failed,so I can not install slime successfully on my emacs.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908598/install-slime-on-emacs-error

Comment: @yeeugene: If you are stuck, see if this guide help. It is how to set up common-lisp, slime & emacs on windows 7-64 http://youtu.be/VnWVu8VVDbI

Comment: Are you running a swank server on port 4005?

Comment: @Baggers: I tried that too.No matter which way to choose to install slime on my window,the slime error always happened.                              file-error "make client process failed" "too many open files" :name "SLIME Lisp" :buffer nil :host "127.0.0.1" :service 29825 :nowait nil

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes,I run swank on the default port 4005

Comment: Sounds like a different program is leaking file handles. Perhaps try process explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and see if there are any obvious problems. Also can you start sbcl without slime? How about if you start sbcl from cmd, and then (ql:quickload :swank) and then (swank:create-server :port 4007) and then in emacs M-x slime-connect and choose port 4007?

Comment: @Baggers: I start sbcl from cmd then start swank at port 4007,slime still canot connect to swank.It shows the same error.

Comment: @yeeugene given that the error is about file handles I would use process explorer to check your file handles. The error may be right. If not then the slime mailing list may be your best bet